# lightning component to display alert message on click of button

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I was trying to create one simple lightning component which have one button and on click of that button, i want to display alert message which is in controller. Its showing error as unknown method:handleClick. Can you please help me with this?
Also if you share links for examples to create lightning components, it will really helpful for me.

**component:**

```
<aura:component> 
    <p>Hello lightning</p> 
    <ui:button aura:id="button" label="Click me" press="{!c.getInput}"/>   
</aura:component>
```

**controller:**

```
({ 
    getInput : function(cmp, event) { 
       alert("hello there!"); 
    }, 
})
```

**app:**

```
<aura:application >
<c:helloWorld /></aura:application>
```

Comment: Please share your code so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with the following code and its working, following is the **screenshot -** 
[image]

App Code -

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" implements="force:appHostable">
    <c:TestClick />
</aura:application>
```

Component -

```
<aura:component> 
    <p>Hello lightning</p> 
    <ui:button aura:id="button" label="Click me" press="{!c.getInput}"/>   
</aura:component>
```

Controller JS -

```
({ 
    getInput : function(cmp, event) { 
      alert("hello there!"); 
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried above code but still giving same error. I called getInput method on press and the same method i have in controller.

Comment: post your entire app, component, js controller code

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: @NirmallyaGhosh Please edit your answer rather than adding a new answer. So just Delete of one of your answer

Comment: @Sofiya
I have attached the success screenshot and all code sample, if works please mark it as answer

Comment: Thanks Nirmallya. I tried with youe example and created new component and its working now. Not able to understand why it was not working previously. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sofiya 
most welcome

Answer (score 0):

Component

```
<aura:component >
    <ui:button label="clickme" press="{!c.getAlert}"/>
    <input type="button" value="clickme"
           onclick="{!c.getAlert}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    getAlert : function(cmp, evt) {
    alert("BUTTON PRESSED");

    }
})
```

Comment: Its giving error as- This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Assertion Failed!: Unknown controller action 'getAlert' : undefined Failing descriptor: {ui$button$controller$press} . Am i missing something?